# Connection to private node (one command tangle) refused

Tags: transaction, iri-node, iota-network, tangle, python

I have created a one command tangle from this link: https://docs.iota.org/docs/utils/0.1/community/one-command-tangle/overview
And using API given here: https://docs.iota.org/docs/node-software/0.1/iri/references/api-reference#broadcasttransactions.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that `sudo docker-compose up` was giving error, so I pulled **coordinator-1264e19** from this link: https://hub.docker.com/r/iotacafe/compass/tags and the command `sudo docker-compose up`started working after this.

I'm trying to broadcast transaction from this node using Python Library, but I'm getting this error:

**"urlopen error [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"**

My code is:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import json

command = {
  "command": "broadcastTransactions",
  "trytes": ["P9KFSJVGSPLXAEBJSHWFZLGP ..."]
}

stringified = json.dumps(command)

headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'X-IOTA-API-Version': '1'
}

url="http://localhost:14265"
fo = urllib.parse.urlencode(command)
#fo = urllib2.urlunparse(command)
fo = fo.encode('utf-8')
request = urllib.request.Request(url, fo)
returnData = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()

jsonData = json.loads(returnData)

print (jsonData)
```

My node is running on ubuntu machine: [image: Text](https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg[![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyIgt.png))

This is very important work for me. If I can get any guidance regarding this error and how to resolve it, I would be very thankful.

Comment: It is unclear for me from where you try to connect. As you connect to localhost, I hope both your node and your python code are running on the same machine/VM? As Compass can issue milestones, it can connect to iri - can you check netstat if the correct process is listening?

Comment: I just noticed that you got error 10061 which is a *Windows* error code. What kind of Python are you running on your *Ubuntu* machine? Python in WINE? Then better try the native Python, as otherwise you might have to deal with some network address mappings...

Comment: On my laptop, I'm running Python 3.7.7. I'm running Python script on VS Code. And my node is running on Ubuntu hosted on Amazon AWS. Python version on Ubuntu is Python 2.7.17

Comment: Then you first have to allow outside connections in your node, and then you need to make sure the AWS firewall has that port open. You can verify with telnet or a web browser. Last but not least, you do not want to connect to localhost, but to the name/ip of your AWS machine.

Comment: My Ubuntu has an IP, so I have to use that IP instead of localhost? Also, how do I allow outside connection to my IOTA node?

Comment: Yes, use that IP (check if it is reachable from your laptop). You can enable outside connections by setting API_HOST to 0.0.0.0 in your config.iri.

Comment: I tried using that IP, but couldn't find config.iri anywhere on my Ubuntu machine.

Comment: The IP is pinging from command prompt. I'm now getting this error: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>

Comment: I don't think it is on topic here how to configure networking or open a port in Amazon AWS. And to be honest I don't know. If you have a SSH connection open to your machine (real SSH client like PuTTY and not a webshell) you could try a port forward in the SSH session to clarify whether the port is really open on the remote machine.